# CSS Translate back from center?

Tags: javascript, html, css, transform

So I wrote some code to translate my box from some location on the window to the center, and I have the original position say, eg:
***ORIGINAL BOX***

```
{
    top: 52.16538619995117, 
    right: 685.6694946289062, 
    bottom: 214.66795349121094, 
    left: 523.1669311523438, 
    width: 150
}
```

The original box width/height is 150px, it then became 300px when it was moved to the center.  Some basic code repositioned it to the center by the following:

```
top = window.innerHeight / 2 - currentPosition.top - 150 /2 
left = window.innerWidth / 2 - currentPosition.left - 150 /2
```

now imagine the new coordinates for the component are:
***CENTERED BOX***

```
{
    top: 74.78038787841797, 
    right: 928.7755126953125, 
    bottom: 374.7803955078125, 
    left: 628.7755126953125, 
    width: 300
}
```

I'm having a hell of a time repositioning it back to the center with :

```
transform: "translate(xTarget, yTarget)";
```

This should be a lot easier than I think it should be but for some reason it is ALWAYS off from the original.

Here is a function I wrote to help determine the translate coordinates:

```
getCoordinateTarget(target, offset, currentNotePosition) {

        const xDifference = target.left - currentNotePosition.left;
        const yDifference = target.top - currentNotePosition.top;
        const xTarget = xDifference > 0 ? xDifference - offset.x : -Math.abs(xDifference) - offset.x;
        const yTarget = yDifference > 0 ? yDifference - offset.y : -Math.abs(yDifference) - offset.y;

        return {
            y: yTarget,
            x: xTarget
        };
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure where the issue is for you, but I thought I'd share that I tackled a similar issue recently. Here's mine (with jQuery): https://github.com/kthornbloom/smoothzoom

Feel free to borrow code if you can!

Comment: I looked at your code but didn't see anything that directly relates.  You're mostly re-positionining components that were static(they were originally at say 85%/10% top/left.  If you could point me directly to what I'm missing?

Thanks man!

Comment: Sorry- must have misread your question!

Comment: no worries mate, thanks for reading the post either way!

Answer (score 0):

Man I had a significant misunderstanding how CSS transforms work.  So I originally moved it with a translate, all I had to do is set the transform to empty and the component will get repositioned back to the original location.

Literally `transform: "";`